# Howto install php 5.2.17 on centos 6 x86_64

Tags: php5, yum, centos6, x86-64

Does anyone know how to install php 5.2.17 on a 64bit centos 6 install? I've got a old legacy system that requires php 5.2.17, but centos 6 only supports php 5.3.

I've installed repo's such as webtatic, but had no luck at all.

Should I rather revert back to centos 5 and install it there?  Any ideas, I am out?

Answer (score 1):

If centos 6 does not support legacy PHP, you are better off running v5 because if you have to mod the OS to trick it into running it, it *could* open up a security hole. Recommend you use the latest PHP and OS. If that's not possible, then make sure you have very tight security when using old PHP. That's why they update their software. I'm looking for a way to get this to work right for you.

EDIT: I was beaten to it. Refer to the other poster's wget method.
EDIT2: removed useless text.

Comment: I'd recommend waiting to submit an answer until you have good content to offer. Doing so will gain you many more upvotes than you would if you post a half-baked answer.

Comment: Even though it can be edited? Okay, sounds like good advice.

Comment: Agree with the updated answer, and Centos 5 will still receive maintenance updates until Spring 14'.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
wget http://www.atoomnet.net/php/php-5.2.17/php-5.2.17-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Then:

```
rpm -ivh php-5.2.17-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Then:

```
vi /etc/yum.conf
```

Add the following under [main]:

```
exclude=php*
```

If you do all that it should work fine.

But, I warn you, you should really run the latest version of PHP to insure that your server is secure.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this already, got too many dependency problems when I want to follow this method.

Comment: Okay, are you having problems with dependencies when installing the rpm package I provided? Or, after excluding php from updates?

Comment: That is correct, you see it's not just installing php, extra extensions is also required such as gd, curl, json ect. The best would be to have a yum repo where one can install these extra extensions as well.

Comment: This should contain all of the extensions: http://www.atoomnet.net/centos_updated_php.php

Answer (score 1):

The atomicturtle repo contains php 5.2.17 x64 rpms for centos 6. Download the necessary packages and install it.

http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/6/x86_64/RPMS/

Updated link: http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/6/x86_64/drpms/